# Creating an npm package from CRA build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

We are trying to create a microfront ends app, we would like to take each micro app (created with CRA) run
npm run build
over this app, take the /build folder created, and make a npm package out of it and publish it to our npm repo.

We don't want to ejact the app projects to be able to edit the webpack.config.

We prefer to take the /build and pass it over webpack again (even in a different project) in order to get an output that can be used as npm package and can be published and imported correctly to a new project.

Im trying doing it by taking the /build folder and running it over webpack with this configuration:

```
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bundle.js": glob
      .sync("build/static/?(js|css)/main.*.?(js|css)")
      .map(f => path.resolve(__dirname, f))
  },
  output: {
    filename: "build/static/js/bundle.min.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.join(__dirname, "./src")
    }
  },
  externals: {
    react: "commonjs react"
  }
};
```

The result is a single js. after publishing it to npm, im trying to import it and getting many errors like:

[image]

I think there is something missing in my webpack.config or maybe there is a different way to take the all /build folder and combine it to something that can be published as npm package and imported correctly?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thank you!